# menus in android studio looks small on my new screen

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-14

I have this weird problem with Android studio that's driving me crazy.

I have a new monitor, with a higher resolution (2560x1440), and on that monitor the toolbar menus looks small, they get reduced to 7 rows and I have no idea how to change this behaviour. So far it is the only software that does this, is there some settings where I can change the height of the menus?

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 if it makes any difference.

[image]
(sorry for the picture I couldn't take a screenshot with the menu open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still don't know if the problem is solvable via any internal setting in Android Studio, I managed to resolve this issue by swapping my HDMI cable with a DisplayPort. What really puzzled me was the fact that only Android studio seemed to be affected.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font size of Android Studio UI. This might help.

File -> Settings -> Appearance and Behavior -> (Tick) Use Custom Font -> Set your desired font size at Right of the **Use Custom Font** option.

[Checkout the Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfUm8.png)